# NodeJS not showing full object, only [Object], for response

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

When sending all documents from the MondoDB database I'm getting the response

```
data: { list: [ [Object], [Object] ] }
```

This is the correct number of documents, and they are objects, but I want to know how I can display the entire document, including nested objects, not just the [Object]. How is this possible? Here's my code:

```
Doc.find({})
            .then((list) => {
                let listToSend = [];

                // push the response data to the array
                for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    listToSend.push(list[i]);
                }

                // send the list once all documents are pushed
                res.send(({ data: listToSend }));
            })
```

Comment: Try using [res.json({data: listToSend });](https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.json)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.stringify, and get some nice formatting

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 4));

console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)));
```

Comment: So this works, but it’s adding +\n when I user spaces. I’ve used json.stringify before without that being added, do you know how to remove it?

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject)));` try this out i have also updated my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the depth of the inspection output (the default is 2) you can manually call the `inspect` function (here I used 6 as example):

```js
import { inspect } from 'util'

console.log(inspect(myObject, { depth: 6 }))
```

Or if you want that to happen all the time by default, you can set the `defaultOptions`:

```js
import { inspect } from 'util'

inspect.defaultOptions.depth = 6
```